# Maya MEL/Python scriptJob. Run script when NonDagObject created

Tags: python, maya, mel

How do I set sriptJob flags if I want to run a script when NonDagObject is created. 
E.G 
After this `shadingNode -asRendering renderPass;` I would like to run function A.
I can't find such event in docs.

Comment: OK, renderPass event exist, but what about other non dag objects?

Comment: There is no event this focused. There is a object added event however so you could check for what new objects you have. But this could be too slow for your need. Is it important to act on creation? Couldn't you defer the creation to some other time such as AE template building or something? Or possibly hook to the GUI creation of the node.

Comment: I think AE template build is what I'm looking for.